# Can JSON Framework be used to upload files to a website like ASIHTTPREQUEST

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I want to download some files from my website and have to upload the modified files into the website. The downloading can be done fine with JSON Frame work. Now I want to know whether I can use this Frame work to upload my files too. If yes please give me some sample application to help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an try the following for posting data to remote php server.

```
NSString *jsonString = [self.dataSource JSONRepresentation];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://remoteserver.com/test.php"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request  setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"]; 
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[request appendPostData:[jsonString  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: Thank you Swapna. But to know is there any other way to upload files without loading ASIHTTPRequest.